# How do I formulate search for "HEADER Delivered-To is not empty" in GMail IMAP? (or SEARCH "[Gmail]/All Mail" and exclude "/Drafts")

Tags: imap, gmail-imap

I'm looking for an IMAP search clause to get GMail's "[Gmail]/All Mail" contents but filter out mails which are in "[Gmail]/Drafts".

IMAP DRAFT flag doesn't help with GMail's IMAP. By comparing full headers, I've noticed that drafts don't have value in "Delivered-To" field - it's missing from the header for all messages in "[Gmail]/Drafts".

I've tried UID search directly on "[Gmail]/Drafts" which has a few messages with following clause/results:

I'm expecting to get a clause which returns no messages - or all messages which have Delivered-To absent:

```
(HEADER Delivered-To "")         <- returns all drafts
(NOT (HEADER Delivered-To ""))   <- negating still returns all drafts!
(NOT HEADER Delivered-To "")     <- still returns all drafts
(HEADER Delivered-To NIL)        <- returns no messages - opposite to expected
(NOT (HEADER Delivered-To NIL))  <- returns all drafts
(NOT HEADER Delivered-To NIL)    <- returns all drafts
(NOT (DRAFT))                    <- returns all drafts
(DRAFT)                          <- returns none - opposite to expected, GMail doesn't seem to flag drafts with DRAFT
```

Will appreciate suggestions for how would you formulate "HEADER Delivered-To is not empty" for GMail IMAP.

Comment: You seem to have assumed a solution, without attacking the problem more directly.  Did you try something along the lines of `UID SEARCH NOT X-GM-LABELS \Draft`?  [Gmail IMAP Extensions](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap_extensions) includes Search Terms for labels, which seems more to be what you want.

Comment: @Max, thank you for the suggestion and the link! I agree about assumption, but had to "engineer" it not finding direct answer. Tried with search - unfortunately it fails on both '[GMail]/All Mail' or on '[Gmail]/Drafts' (plural) even without "NOT": `29:27.40 imap.gmail.com writer > BGOD4 UID SEARCH (X-GM-LABELS (\Drafts))\r\n
29:27.50 imap.gmail.com reader < BGOD4 BAD Could not parse command\r\n`

Comment: @Max, but searching just for "foo" works: `> NBHH4 UID SEARCH (X-GM-LABELS foo)\r\n
< * SEARCH\r\n`, the question is how to search for \Drafts.. I'm using Python's imaplib2 if it makes any difference.. Sometimes it duplicates \ as \\.. So still `> HIPP4 UID SEARCH (X-GM-LABELS (\Drafts))\r\n
< HIPP4 BAD Could not parse command\r\n` and without parens `> HNEN4 UID SEARCH (X-GM-LABELS \Drafts)\r\n
 < HNEN4 BAD Could not parse command\r\n`

Comment: Maybe "\Drafts" with quotes.

Comment: @Max, unfortunately "-s don't do: `status, uidsString = M.uid('search', None, '(X-GM-LABELS "\Drafts")')` results in `> OONJ4 UID SEARCH (X-GM-LABELS "\Drafts")\r\n
< OONJ4 BAD Could not parse command\r\n`;  but double (*2) slash treated as non-existing label `M.uid('search', None, '(X-GM-LABELS "\\\\Drafts")')` results in legal search but no results `> OCIF4 UID SEARCH (X-GM-LABELS "\\Drafts")\r\n
< * SEARCH\r\n`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though not a direct answer, I ended up downloading bodies of new messages and scanning them for flags.

Answer (score 1):

```
x uid search header "delivered-to" "@"
```

The HEADER key searches for a header field with the given name containing the given substring. That is, header "foo" "" searches for messages that have a foo header field, empty or not. There is no proper way to search for messages that have a nonempty field.

However, you can get around that with a hack in this case: Every nonempty Delivered-To contains an @ sign, so just search for @ and you get the result you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for the try, I'm running it with Python's imaplib, got `  52:57.59 MainThread [sync] SELECT ('[Gmail]/Drafts',)
  52:57.75 MainThread state => SELECTED
  53:00.12 MainThread [async] UID ('SEARCH', None, '(ALL) (X UID SEARCH HEADER "Delivered-To" "@")')`

Comment: .. even tried to patch python lib to preserve the order of words but still no luck:
  26:04.17 MainThread [async] X UID ('SEARCH', None, "HEADER Delivered-To '@'")
  26:04.25 imap.gmail.com handler BAD response: Unknown command: X

Comment: Looks like you need to leave out the 'x'. Each IMAP command is prefixed by a tag: you can send several at a time, and the tag helps to disambiguate. I expect Python's imaplib adds a tag of its own.